# Using NuGet to Install Metri UI CSS on mac

Tags: macos, user-interface, installation, microsoft-metro, nuget

I'm learning web design and I found Metro UI CSS and I want to instal the package. The instruction says use NuGet to instal the package. I'm using a mac I want to know how to install a NuGet so that i can instal Metro UI package? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use NuGet you need to install [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/).  You can do it by  using `brew install mono` if you use [brew](http://brew.sh/).  Or you can install [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/platform), which installs Mono with himself.

After that you can use NuGet:

```
# demas at MacBook-Air-demas.local in ~ [6:20:23]
$ nuget install Metro-UI-CSS
Attempting to resolve dependency 'WebActivatorEx (≥ 2.0.4)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure (≥ 1.0.0.0)'.
...
Installing 'Metro-UI-CSS 2.0.31.1'.
Successfully installed 'Metro-UI-CSS 2.0.31.1'.
```